# como llenar una tabla de forma horizontal en primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```html
<p:dataTable id="consultaIncidencia" styleClass="columns" var="incidenciaDet" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.incidenciaAnioMesDet}">
  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
      <p:column headerText="RFC" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
      <p:column headerText="Nombre" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
      <p:column headerText="Clave" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
      <ui:repeat value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.listDias}" var="dia">
        <p:column headerText="#{dia}" />
      </ui:repeat>

    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText />
  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText />
  </p:column>
  <p:column styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText />
  </p:column>
  <p:columns value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.listDias}" var="dia" styleClass="columns">
    <h:outputText />
  </p:columns>

</p:dataTable>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo el siguiente codigo, en el cual mando a llamar mi consulta

```
    incidenciaAnioMesDet = anioMesDetService.findIncidenciaAnioMesDeByAnioMes(2018, 1, cvePersona);
   for(IncidenciaAnioMesDet incidencia: incidenciaAnioMesDet)
        System.out.println("PRUEBA" + " DIA-" +incidencia.getDia() + " INCIDENCIA-" + incidencia.getIncidencias().getCveIdIncidencia());
```

y me arroja lo siguiente en consola:

PRUEBA DIA-3 INCIDENCIA-3
PRUEBA DIA-4 INCIDENCIA-4,
PRUEBA DIA-5 INCIDENCIA-5
PRUEBA DIA-2 INCIDENCIA-15
PRUEBA DIA-1 INCIDENCIA-1

ahora lo que quiero es que ese numero de incidencia mostrarlo en el numero de dia que dice pero dentro de mi tabla, pero no me aparece nada

como puedo mostrar esa info que quiero en la parte

```html
                                 
                                <p:columns value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.listDias}" var="dia" styleClass="columns">
                                    <h:outputText />
                                </p:columns>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer para poder mostrar la información de tu lista en la tabla es usar una variable con la que puedes acceder a la lista y sus atributos.

En tu caso ya la tienes es  `var="incidenciaDetvar="incidenciaDet`

```
<p:dataTable id="consultaIncidencia" styleClass="columns" 
var="incidenciaDet" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" value="# 
{RegistroAccesoComponent.incidenciaAnioMesDet}">
```

La tabla quedaria de esta manera solo lo pongo como ejemplo `incidenciaDet.dia`  porque que atributos tiene tu objeto

```
<p:dataTable id="consultaIncidencia" styleClass="columns" 
var="incidenciaDet" style="max-width:3000px;max-height:770px;" value="#
{RegistroAccesoComponent.incidenciaAnioMesDet}">

<p:columnGroup type="header">
  <p:row>
   <p:column headerText="RFC" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
  <p:column headerText="Nombre" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
  <p:column headerText="Clave" styleClass="columns" style="width:110px;height:50px" />
  <ui:repeat value="#{RegistroAccesoComponent.listDias}" var="dia">
    <p:column headerText="#{dia}" />
  </ui:repeat>
</p:row>

 </p:columnGroup>
 <p:column styleClass="columns">
 <h:outputText value="#{incidenciaDet.dia} />
 </p:column>
 <p:column styleClass="columns">
 <h:outputText value="#{incidenciaDet.dia} />
 </p:column>
 <p:column styleClass="columns">
 <h:outputText value="#{incidenciaDet.dia} />
 </p:column>
 <p:columns value="#{incidenciaDet}" var="dia" styleClass="columns">
 <h:outputText />
 </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```